# Error: Initializer provided for function, __THROW __asm

Tags: c++, arm, g++

I am trying to port an ARM-C library to be compiled with x86_64 C++, and I am getting the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:40,
                 from MyFile.h:19,
/usr/include/wchar.h:226:20: error: initializer provided for function
       __THROW __asm ("wcschr") __attribute_pure__;
                     ^
```

where *MyFile.h* has the following structure

```
// comments
#pragma once
// comments
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>              //<<< line 19

…
```

Initially, instead of  it used to be  which gave me a similar error:

```
In file included from MyFile.h:19:
/usr/include/string.h:73:21: error: initializer provided for function
          __THROW __asm ("memchr") __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1));
                        ^
```

Compiler version:

```
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
           compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11) 2.23
```

Compilation flags:

```
#g++ -O3 -std=c++14 -fpermissive -Wno-system-headers -w
```

### UPDATE 1:

<strike>I've been modifying the `Makefile`, and the original version contains `$@.via`. For instance:</strike>

```
@$(COMPILE) -M -MF $(subst .o,.d.tmp,$@) -MT $@ -E $(C_FLAGS) $@.via $< -o $@.preprocessed.c
```

and I changed the `$@.via` for `@$@.via` because I saw that in an older project they did it like that. However, if I leave as `$@.via` I just get:

```
SomeFile.c:1:1 fatal error: OneHeader.h: No such file or directory
```

I am starting to think that my `Makefile` is somewhere wrong...

I misunderstood the compiler option... Few lines above, my makefile creates the `@.via` files passing **DEFINES** and **INCLUDES**

```
       @echo $(patsubst %, '%', $(C_DEFINES)) > $@.via
       @echo $(C_INCLUDE) >> $@.via
```

and those `@.via` files are passed as additional arguments for the compilation. While for `armcc` the `--via` is supported [see here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/index.html), I found that for g++ -according to the [gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)- the syntax is `@<your_file>`. Thus, what `@$@.via` does is simply to parse the `$@.via` to `<your_file>.via`.

Now I am still getting the `initializer provided for function` error message.

### UPDATE 2:

***I found the problem and I explained what happened in the answer section. See below.***

Comment: The error is not in your myfile.h line 19 but in `/usr/include/wchar.h`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie but that's part of the Gnu libc, so I dont think that's the error, or you could please elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Root cause

The problem was originated because I redefined `__asm` to be replaced by nothing (e.g. `#define __asm`) since I didn't want to touch the assembly code yet. Remember that I said I am porting ARM to x86, so I thought that  easiest way to get rid of the compile errors was to remove all those `__asm` instructions, but not considering the effects of doing such a thing.

In other words, when I included the `string.h` header, the header itself uses assembly call as the error messaged pointed out:

```
/usr/include/wchar.h:226:20: error: initializer provided for function
       __THROW __asm ("wcschr") __attribute_pure__;
```

and when the preprocessor changed the `__asm("wcschr")` for `("wcschr")` the compiler hits the error -- which makes sense.

### Moral of the history

Do not redefine qualifiers since it will also affect other modules that you are not seeing directly and prefer creating a macro to just change them (e.g. `__asm` for `/*__asm*/`) or just run `sed` in you code base.

Comment: I'm encountering this bug myself. I am trying to run unit tests on my ARM program in a x86 environment. When I compile my code in Cygwin G++ in Windows, it compiles fine. But when I try to compile with G++ on Linux I get the errors you were encountering.